# Change Chart Line Color from Datasource

Tags: vb.net, graph, charts

When adding a series with points to the chart, I can change the color whenever I want like this:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 8
        Chart1.Series(0).Points(i).Color = Color.Blue
Next
For i As Integer = 9 To 12
        Chart1.Series(0).Points(i).Color = Color.Red
Next
```

But now Im just adding a datasource as datatable, and would like to change the color of some part of the line. How can I approach this? Thanks

Comment: What does "change the color of some part of the line" mean?

Comment: Pretty sure you will find the colour for the lines is set for the entire series.  You may be able to get away with splitting your data into multiple series?

Comment: Yes I finally did the splitting the data into two different series, Thanks!